# How to get substring after a pattern appeared twice?

Tags: string, bash

Here is the top command output (after grep):

```
%Cpu(s):  1.0 us,  0.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.3 id,  0.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  856 root      20   0  528808 169460 161064 S   0.0  2.1  23:03.96 Xorg
%Cpu(s):  0.5 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  856 root      20   0  528808 169460 161064 S   0.0  2.1  23:03.96 Xorg
```

I only need the second half. So how can I get the text from the second `%Cpu(s)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
command | grep <something> | tail -1
```

Comment: thanks, however, it is in multi-line, so tail -1 will not get the full 2nd half as expected

Answer (score 0):

an alternative for `gawk` with `RT` support - no need for `grep`-ing:

```
command | gawk -v block=3 -v RS='%Cpu[(]s[)]' 'FNR==block{print rt $0}{rt=RT}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple awk:

```
command | awk '/^%Cpu/ { mrk+=1 } mrk==2 { print $0 }'
```

When we encounter a line beginning with %Cpu, we increment a marker variable mrk. When this variable is 2 we print the lines.

Comment: What happens if you have 5 %Cpu lines/blocks and you want to output the 3rd one ONLY?

Comment: Well the scenario was only 2 cpus but, if there are more, you simply change the mrk==... directive accordingly.

Comment: If I use mrk==1 it printed out full text. if I use mrk==2, it printed nothing ...?

Comment: What command are you running?. This works if I place your example text in a file and process that